# "Not an entity" error happened when defining a custom sort column

Tags: corda

I based on the tutorial code for my project, and I changed the concept IOU to LegalContract, and it has some new added custom properties, below is the constructor of the LegalContract which is under model folder:

```
@CordaSerializable
data class LegalContract(var legalEntity: String,
                         var contractTitle: String,
                         var contractType: String,
                         var effectiveDate: String,
                         var expirationDate: String,
                         var peerLegalEntity: String,
                         var contractFile: String,
                         var contractFileHash: String,
                         var linearId: String = "",
                         var status: String)
```

I want to add a sorting option by its contract title property. After search on documentation, there is not a sample about using one customized property as the sorting option, and from the corda core code, I found below sample in the VaultQueryTests.kt:

```
val sorting = Sort(setOf(Sort.SortColumn(SortAttribute.Custom(DummyLinearStateSchemaV1.PersistentDummyLinearState::class.java, "linearString"), Sort.Direction.DESC)))
```

in the Api code, I defined a sort variable follow above's sample, and below is my updated code

```
val sorting: Sort = Sort(setOf(Sort.SortColumn(SortAttribute.Custom(LegalContractSchemaV1.PersistentLegalContract::class.java, "contract_title"), Sort.Direction.ASC)))
val vaultStates = services.vaultQueryBy<LegalContractState>(sorting=sorting)
return vaultStates.states
```

I have below LegalContractSchema defined in the schema folder, and the class PersistentLegalContract is a persistent state type:

```
object LegalContractSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(
        schemaFamily = LegalContractSchema.javaClass,
        version = 1,
        mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentLegalContract::class.java)) {
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "legal_contract_states")
    class PersistentLegalContract(
            @Column(name = "contract_title")
            var contractTitle: String,

            @Column(name = "sender_name")
            var senderName: String,

            @Column(name = "recipient_name")
            var recipientName: String,

            @Column(name = "status")
            var status: String
    ) : PersistentState()
}
```

But when I run nodes and wants to get the contracts returned, below error happened.

```
vault.HibernateVaultQueryImpl._queryBy - Not an entity: class com.legalcontract.schema.LegalContractSchemaV1$PersistentLegalContract
```

Below is my state definition code:

```
data class LegalContractState(var legalContract: LegalContract,
                              val sender: Party,
                              var recipient: Party,
                              override val contract: LegalContractCode,
                              override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()):
        LinearState, QueryableState {
    //override val contractCode get() = LegalContractCode()
    /** The public keys of the involved parties. */
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty> get() {
        return listOf(sender, recipient)
    }

    /** Tells the vault to track a state if we are one of the parties involved. */
    override fun isRelevant(ourKeys: Set<PublicKey>) = ourKeys.intersect(participants.flatMap { it.owningKey.keys }).isNotEmpty()

    override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState {
        return when (schema) {
            is LegalContractSchemaV1 -> LegalContractSchemaV1.PersistentLegalContract(
                    contractTitle = this.legalContract.contractTitle,
                    senderName = this.sender.name.toString(),
                    recipientName = this.recipient.name.toString(),
                    status = this.legalContract.status
            )
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema")
        }
    }

    override fun supportedSchemas(): Iterable<MappedSchema> = listOf(LegalContractSchemaV1)
}
```

As there is limited sample code about this, so I am not sure what shall I do to fix this issue. Anyone can provide some comments/guidance? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you made your state object a subclass of `QueryableState` and overridden `generateMappedObject` and `supportedSchemas`?

Comment: hi @joel, yes I think it is defined as you mentioned, I add my state definition code into the post, and most of its structure are from the default tutorial code.

Comment: How are you interacting with the node when you get this error? Is the error thrown within a flow, or within a query attempt?

Comment: in the api file, by default when retrieve all states, there is no any search criteria or sorting, I just plan to add a sorting to the default query, and I got this error both on the command window and the log

Comment: in the api file, by default when retrieve all states, there is no any search criteria or sorting, I just plan to add a sorting to the default query, and I got this error both on the command window and the log

Comment: Ah - so the query works without the sorting?

Comment: Yes @joel, it works well without the new added sorting option.

Comment: And @joel, I tried to clone the M13 tutorial code, and just add a sorting for "ious" api code, and also encounter "Not an entity" error, I wanted to use the iou value as the sorting column. Changed code as below
`    @GET
    @Path("ious")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun getIOUs(): List<StateAndRef<IOUState>> {
        val sorting = Sort(setOf(Sort.SortColumn(SortAttribute.Custom(IOUSchemaV1.PersistentIOU::class.java, "value"), Sort.Direction.DESC)))
        val vaultStates = services.vaultQueryBy<IOUState>(sorting = sorting)
        return vaultStates.states
    }`

Comment: I think you are missing the registration of your custom schema in the CordaPlugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the registration of your custom schema in the CordaPluginRegistry configuration. Admittedly this information could be more clearly highlighted in our [documentation](https://docs.corda.net/api-vault.html?highlight=api%20query).

It currently states:
*"It is a requirement to register any custom contract schemas to be used in Vault Custom queries in the associated CordaPluginRegistry configuration for the respective CorDapp using the requiredSchemas configuration field (which specifies a set of MappedSchema)"*

`// Plugin.
class MyCordappPlugin : CordaPluginRegistry(), WebServerPluginRegistry {
    override val requiredSchemas: Set<MappedSchema> = setOf(LegalContractSchemaV1)
}`

If you are additionally writing JUnit tests then you need to register your custom schema when creating a HibernateConfiguration object:

`database.transaction {
            val hibernateConfig = HibernateConfiguration(NodeSchemaService(setOf(LegalContractSchemaV1)), makeTestDatabaseProperties())`

Comment: Hi, two things happened after follow your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

What two things happened to you?
  For me, I had to add a dummy constructor for the PersistentState, and I had to put the jar containing the MappedSchema object in the Controller node's plugins folder in order to start the test network. Both seemed to very strange to me, especially the second one.  Why would the Controller know the custom plugins?

\Sean